# Silverstripe 3 - Use dropdown Yes/No for a Boolean $db field in the CMS

Tags: php, silverstripe

I don't like the standard checkbox supplied for Boolean DB fields in the CMS. Pretty easy to miss. And an Enum complicates it's use in templates a little.

Is there a way I can hook a Boolean DB field into a DropdownField in getCMSFields? I have tried the following, which displays fine, but doesn't actually save a value to the DB field, or even read the value and set accordingly.

```
private static $db = [
    'HasTalkPage' => 'Boolean'
];

public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $fields->removeByName('HasTalkPage');

    $hasTalkPage = DropdownField::create('HasTalkPage', 'Needs a page?', array(1 => 'Yes', 0 => 'No'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $hasTalkPage);

    return $fields;
}
```

Also tried with true/false in that array instead of 1/0 but same issue.

Comment: Your code works fine for me on SilverStripe 4.1. Which version are you using?

Comment: @RobbieAverill it's 3.x. I found the solution and answered my own question below.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution to this in someone else's code. It seems the fields needs a ->saveInto() command added to it.

```
$hasTalkPage = DropdownField::create('HasTalkPage', 'Needs a page?', array(1 => 'Yes', 0 => 'No'), $this->HasTalkPage);
$hasTalkPage->saveInto($this);
$fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $hasTalkPage);
```

Judging by Robbie Averill's comment to my original post, this might just be a SilverStripe 3 thing. Sounds like my original code works fine in 4.